# Want to implement a logic which automatically calculate the percentage of network availability for pandas duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Snapshot for better understand]

Here i calculated Percentage of Network Availability Using following formula in excel for 172.31.141.205 :

First one : ((31 * 24 * 60)-(E2+E3+E4+E5+E6)*60) / (((31 * 24 * 60)-((E2+E3) * 60)) * 100%

above i subtract all 'Total duration' * 60 from (31 * 24 * 60) and divide this ((31 * 24 * 60)-((E2+E3) * 60)) here (E2+E3) is subtracted because 'Fault Domain" entry is BCC.

- Another one formula for 172.31.141.88 :

(((31 * 24 * 60)-(E7+E8) * 60) / (((31 * 24 * 60)-(( E7) * 60)) * 100%

above i subtract all 'Total duration' * 60 from (31 * 24 * 60) and divide this (((31 * 24 * 60)-(E7) * 60)) here (E7) is subtracted because 'Fault Domain" entry is BCC.

Is  their any universal logic for duplicate rows to calculate Percentage of Network availability using 'Total Duration' and conditions on 'Fault Domain' ?

Please kindly check the snapshot for better understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
AR_IP = ["172.31.141.205","172.31.141.205","172.31.141.205","172.31.141.205","172.31.141.205",
         "172.31.141.88","172.31.141.88"]
notifi_date = ["10/9/2018 14:20","10/9/2018 14:20","10/9/2018 14:20","10/9/2018 14:20",
               "10/9/2018 14:20","10/17/2018 10:20","10/17/2018 10:20"]
rest_date = ["10/10/2018 16:00","10/10/2018 16:00","10/10/2018 16:00","10/10/2018 16:00",
             "10/10/2018 16:00","10/17/2018 13:00","10/17/2018 15:00"]
duration = ["25:39","30:23","7:30","50:10","25:39","2:40","4:40"]
fault_domain = ["BCC","BCC","F@H","F@H","F@H","BCC","F@H"]
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ar_ip' : AR_IP,
        'notifi_date' : notifi_date,
        'rest_date' :rest_date,
        "duration":duration,
        'fault_domain':fault_domain
    })

df['duration'] = df.duration.map(lambda x : int(str(x).split(':')[0])*60 + int(str(x).split(':')[1]))
all_duration = (31 * 24 * 60 )

# Group with only BCC
bcc_faulted_duration = df[df['fault_domain']=='BCC'].groupby(by=['ar_ip']).sum()

# Group with all faults
all_faulted_duration = df.groupby(by='ar_ip').sum()

# Using your formula
# (all_duration - faulted_duration) / (all_duration - bcc_faulted_duration) * 100

perc_nw_avail = (all_duration - all_faulted_duration) / (all_duration - bcc_faulted_duration) * 100
```

Just that am not getting your formula correct ... But guess you wanted to implement in python ... You could get started with this .

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want to add another duplicated rows column where Fault Domain is F@H and output stored  into dataframe for all  .How can calculate this along with your provided solution? Following Below is respective column name for value :
{Month,AR IP,Notification Date & Time,Restoration Date & Time,Total Duration,Fault Domain,Percentage}
[October-18, 172.31.86.90, 10/28/2018 10:49, 10/28/2018  14:20,  3:30, F@H]
[October-18, 172.31.86.90, 10/21/2018 10:53, 10/21/2018  14:20,  3:26, F@H]

Comment: You could control the fault domain required based on controlling the df filter here : 
df[df['fault_domain']=='BCC'] .Consider having fault domains to a list and call them one at a time in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can use locking logic in excel. Moreover try not to write length syntax. it makes reading unclear.

The locking logic:
((31 * 24 * 60)-SUM($E$2:$E$6)*60) / (((31 * 24 * 60)-(($E$2+$E$3) * 60)) * 100%

And once the output is generated then reference it to the cell where you want the same output with the help of =

Comment: i want to implement this using python pandas.Is there any solution?